# Pyserial cannot write to tty like the linux shell

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, pyserial, uart

I can communicate with a device over UART with the following command in the linux shell:

```
echo 'CMD' > /dev/ttyPS1
```

I tried to recreate this action in Python using the Pyserial module, but nothing happens. I have tried to use it in both a .py file as well as inside of 2.7 interpreter (in case of timing delay issues).

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyPS1', 115200)
ser.write('CMD')
```

Interestingly enough... after running the snippet of python, I cannot write to the device using the linux shell. stty shows me that Pyserial has added a bunch of options to the device. If I clear these extra options, then I can use the linux shell to talk with my device again.

Before Python script:

```
>>> stty -F /dev/ttyPS1
speed 115200 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel
```

After Python script:

```
>>> stty -F /dev/ttyPS1
speed 115200 baud; line = 0;
min = 0; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

Why is this behavior happening? Is there a way to make Pyserial act like the linux shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to make `pyserial` open the device file without changing all those flags, or explicitly make it change the flags to exactly the values they already have, you can probably do that with a bunch of option arguments to [the constructor](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#classes), or maybe by setting some attributes or calling some methods after construction.

---

But why do you want to do that?

If you just want to do the equivalent of `echo`, just do what the shell and `echo` command are doing: open the device file as a file and write to it.

So, one of these:

```
with open('/dev/ttyPS1', 'wb') as ps1:
    ps1.write(b'CMD')

with open('/dev/ttyPS1', 'wb', buffering=0) as ps1:
    ps1.write(b'CMD')

with open('/dev/ttyPS1', 'wb') as ps1:
    ps1.raw.write(b'CMD')

ps1 = os.open('/dev/ttyPS1', os.O_WRONLY)
os.write(ps1, b'CMD')
os.close(ps1)
```

---

If you're using Python 2.x, you don't need the `b` prefixes, and there is no `.raw`, but otherwise things are similar:

```
with open('/dev/ttyPS1', 'wb') as ps1:
    ps1.write('CMD')

with open('/dev/ttyPS1', 'wb', 0) as ps1:
    ps1.write('CMD')

ps1 = os.open('/dev/ttyPS1', os.O_WRONLY)
os.write(ps1, 'CMD')
os.close(ps1)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I could directly write to the device file. All the documentation had been using the Pyserial library so I was stuck in that mentality. I would like to add that when I wrote directly to the file, I had to add '\n' or else the command didn't go through.

Comment: @ShahA Sure, but you’d have to do that with `pyserial` as well. The `echo` command adds a newline unless you tell it not to, like Python’s `print`, but unlike `write`.